# How to compare the counts of two dataframes in PySpark?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using PySpark where I am building Temporary Views out of dataframes. As part of it, I would like to know how to compare the counts of two dataframes and if they don't match, throw an error.

My code looks like this:

```
df1 = spark.sql ("""SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 FROM Table1""")
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")

df2 = spark.sql ("""SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM Table2""")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("df2")

df_join = spark.sql ("""SELECT Table1.Col1, Table1.Col2 FROM Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1""")
df_join .createOrReplaceTempView("df_join")
```

The counts of df1 and df_join should always match. So, I would like to compare the counts between these two dataframes and throw an error if those doesn't match.

Looking for some help here please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataFrame object has count() method: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.count

So it's going to be as simple as:

```
if df1.count() != df_join.count():
    raise ValueError('Dataframes counts doesnt match')
```

Comment: This seems to be the one I'm looking for but it is killing the performance. Any tips to tune this? Also, when I raise the error, I would also like to display the counts of both the dataframes. How do I do that?

Comment: I kind of figured it out. I've assigned the count to a variable and then printing it. But, still looking to make this little more performant.

Comment: Unfortunately optimizer have to perform full table/dataframe scan to get row count. However, you can reduce overall execution time with fewer scans doing count during intermediate SQL execution and data collection

Answer (score 1):

From the join, add the count with the condition.

```
df_join = spark.sql("""
    SELECT 
        Table1.Col1,
        Table1.Col2,
        count(Table1.Col1) as CountDF1,
        count(IF(Table2.Col1 is not null, 1)) as CountDF2
    FROM 
        Table1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        Table2 
    ON 
        Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1
""")
```

And compare those two counts.

Or you just can compare it simply as follows:

```
df1.count() == df2.count()
```

Comment: Thank you! Would adding the count in the df itself gain any performance?